# emails from exchange 2010 go to hotmail's junk folder

Tags: exchange-2010

We have been using our current exchange 2010 server for more than 5 months and everything was ok until yesterday that I was asked to add a new accepted domain to the server for another department.
I did it all work fine, but since then not only emails from the new domain end up in hotmail junk folder but also our main exchange domain  emails go to junk as well.
I don't understand as I didn't change anything in the old domain.
the IP is clean. We have spf and ptr records for both domains and they both pass hotmail verification. 
is there anything which I,was supposed to do when I added the accepted domain?